# Probability man women in a survey

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, word-problem

> In a survey, we asked $7$ men and $5$ women. Is randomly selected without replacement persons one by one until a man. Let $X$ be a random variable of the number of prints required.
>
> - Determine the values of $X$ and its probability distribution.

The original French text version:

> [image]

**My thoughts:**
for example we can have this outcomes 
 - M , WM , WWM , WWWM , WWWWM and WWWWWM

$\Pr(X=1)=7/12,\ \Pr(X=2)=(5.7)/(12.11),\  \Pr(X=3)=(5.4.7)/(12.11.10),$  $ \Pr(X=4)=(5.4.3.7)/(12.11.10.9),\  \Pr(X=5)=(5.4.3.2.7)/(12.11.10.9.8).$

$\Pr(X=6)=(5.4.3.2.1.7)/(12.11.10.9.8.7).$

- $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{k=1}^6 k \, P(X=k),$
- $\operatorname{Var}(X)=  \operatorname{E}\left[X^2 \right] - (\operatorname{E}[X])^2$
- Is my proof correct?
- Is my translation of French text correct?
- Is there any probability distributions from that [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) can apply it to solve the exercise?

Comment: All of this should be done **without replacement** so your numbers will get smaller at each step.  $P([X=4])=\frac{5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 7}{12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9}$ for example.  Once someone has been picked, they can not be picked again.

Comment: Thanks yeah i just thinking about that i will correct my thoughts right away

Comment: see my update please

Comment: With the edit, that is correct for part $1$.  Now apply the definitions to complete part $2$ to find $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$.

Comment: okay i will thanks

Comment: Almost right. It is possible that $X=6$.  The probability of this is calculated in the same way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you could you correct my translation in English

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have already figured it out from the comments, but I think that an alternative approach can be helpful in gaining a better understanding of this kind of problem.

If you think of all the ways in which you can pick all the individuals randomly without replacement, it equals the number of ways in which you can pick the 5 positions for the women times possible orderings. That's

$$
{12 \choose 5} 5! 7!
$$

Now, if you consider the possibilities in which the first man comes up at position $k$, for some $k$ such that $1 \leq k \leq 6$, that amounts to fixing the genders at the first $k$ positions and considering all possibilities for the remaining $12-k$, which again multiplied by the possible reorderings is

$$
{12-k \choose 5-k+1 } 5!7!
$$

Therefore, the probability that the first man will appear at position $k$ is simply

$$
P(X=k) = \frac{{12-k \choose 5-k+1 }}{{12 \choose 5 }}
$$

for all $k$ such that $1 \leq k \leq 6$.

Comment: is my translation of french text correct

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, so I should not be the one to answer that question. I'm sure you can get help at english.stackexchange.com

Comment: i tag translation-request

Comment: is there any  probability distributions from that list can apply it to solve the exercise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions